# There are 5 Parallel request executing in under 1 TR controller of Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Let,c These below are the 5 request in one Transaction controller

https//detailslist/Json/1

https//detailslist/Json/2

https//detailslist/Json/3

https//detailslist/Json/4

https//detailslist/Json/5

Note : Above request are executing parallel in browser and the response time of the browser is one of the highest response time of the request (request 4 is having high response time i;e 6 sec and this is the total response time of this page)

In Jmeter what is happening, It is giving response time sum of all 5 request i;e 12 sec.Which is higher than browser.

How we can do this in Jmeter. is there any solution or option are available in jmeter to execute request parallel in jmeter.

Thanks in advance to people who will answer.

Comment: I read about synchronizing timer use to handle to the parallel request in Jmeter. Where we have to use synchronizing on REQUEST LEVEL or on TRANSACTION CONTROLLER on LEVEL.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter executes sequentially samplers under Transaction Sampler.

There is an enhancement request for that but I am not sure it will be implemented one day:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53159

To do this , you would have to code a JSR223 Sampler using groovy as a language for example.

Answer (score 0):

Currently JMeter cannot kick off any extra threads to simulate the behaviour so the options are in:

1. Write your [custom sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf) which will kick off several parallel threads from JMeter Thread
2. Use scripting-enabled sampler like [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) or [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

See [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) guide for more detailed explanation and some reference code for points 1 and 2